# VBA to VB.NET - Regex - System.Text.RegularExpressions - with no global modifier

Tags: regex, vb.net, vba

I am trying to migrate a lib of regular expressions (utilities) from `VBA` to `VB.NET`, as (my general impression is that) it offers more support to obtain "clean" and re-usable code (including Regex support).

The library is a `factory pattern` to reuse `compiled` regex'es (for performance optimization purposes; not sure at which extend the option `RegexOptions.Compiled` can help it). It is used in combination with a `Lib` that holds records of patterns (utilities) and returns an object; which, besides the `pattern` includes also the `modifiers` (as properties).

However, the `RegEx` object of `System.Text.RegularExpressions` does not have a clean system to specify `flags` / `modifiers`...

```
' VBA
Dim oRegExp As New RegExp
With oRegExp
    .Pattern = Pattern
    .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    .Multiline = Multiline
    .Global = MatchGlobal
End With
```

**Versus**

```
' VB.NET
Dim opts As RegexOptions = New RegexOptions

If IgnoreCase Then opts = opts Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
If Multiline Then opts = opts Or RegexOptions.Multiline

Dim oRegExp As RegEx 
oRegExp = New RegEx(Pattern, opts)

'Were can I specify MatchGlobal???
```

As I do not see this as an improvement to this part of the code, I will rely on applying `inline modifiers` instead ([these here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)) (directly embedded to the `Pattern` itself), and get rid of the object of the library of patterns that includes the modifiers as properties (not included in the examples).

That way...

```
' This -> "\bpre([^\r\n]+)\b" 
' in .NET, can be this -> "\bpre(?<word>\w*)\b"
' as .NET supports named groups 

Dim Pattern as String = "(?i)\bpre(?<word>\w*)\b" ' case insensitive
```

The only **problem** is that, as shown at the `VB.NET` example above, the `RegEx` object of the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions` **seems not** to allow you **changing the global match** modifier (and `inline modifiers`, logically, do not include the `global match flag`).

Any idea on how to deal with it?

Comment: Just assume `MatchGlobal` is always true - `System.Text.RegularExpressions` doesn't have the concept of limiting the result set to the first match. Just use the first match if that's all you need.

Comment: @Comintern: thanks for your answer. Ok, I see... however, that doesn't seem an optimal solution in performance... as it fetches all the found records every time, even when you just need the first match

Comment: Then just write your express to only match the first instance - i.e. with a start of line anchor `^`.

Comment: @Comintern: ok... it seems to work (far fewer steps: 37)... you mean something like this: `(?i)^(?:.)*?\bpre(?<word>\w*)\b`, don't you? (following the example). However, it needs multiline `(?im)^(?:.)*?\bpre(?<word>\w*)\b` (~ 37 steps * number of lines), otherwise, does not catch when match placed beyond first line

Comment: Ok, `multiline` can be avoided with different preceding pattern: `(?i)^[\s\S]*?\bpre(?<word>\w*)\b` (steps: ~ 37 * line of the first match)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for a `global` *regex option* as this behavior is implemented via two different methods.

To only get the first (one) match use [`Regex.Match`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

To match all occurrences, use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Searches an input string for all occurrences of a regular expression and returns all the matches.

You need to implement the logic: if all matches are expected, trigger `Regex.Matches`, if only one, use `Regex.Match`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense (in terms of implementation)... although I still do not understand why they did not follow the Regex specs in regards to global modifiers. Thank you for your answer Wiktor.